# Remove unchanged input fields from Form while submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

In my web application I have edit profile page. In editprofile page their is many fields like

```
Name            : <input type="text" name="name"/>
Location        : <input type="text" class="geolocation" name="location">
Birthdata       : <input type="date" name="dob">
Profile Picture : <input type="file" name="photo"/>
```

I want to send back the data of only the fields which are edited and not all the fields.

Comment: Are you using a standard "submit" behavior or is it via web-services/wcf?  For WCF/webservices, filtering the items would follow follow manoj's solution (storing the original value and comparing before including the values).  For the submit, you'll probably need to follow smerny's solution (storing the original value and removing the input tags).

Comment: I'm using normal Submit of Form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd normally do something like this on the backend.... but for your requirement you could remove the inputs that haven't changed. When you generate the html you can define an extra data attribute. Here's how I would do that:

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" id="Name" data-initial="Foo" value="Foo" />
    <input type="text" id="Location" data-initial="Bar" value="Bar" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$("#myform").submit( function() {
    $(this).find("input").filter( function() {
        $this = $(this);
        return $this.data("initial") == $this.val();
    }).remove();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uLe7T/
I added an alert in the fiddle so you can see that they are removed before the form is submitted

Answer (score 2):

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/DmC4b/)**

HTML

```
<input id="test" type="text" value="Some Text" data-value="Some Text">
```

JS

```
$('#test').blur(function() {
    el = $(this);
    if (el.val() != el.attr('data-value')) {
        console.log('Edited');
    } else {
        console.log('Not Edited');
    }
});
```